# Computed column as PK

Tags: t-sql, primary-key, calculated-columns

I have a computed column based on another column that I want to use as a PK.  I have it set up this way but when trying to create foreign keys it always claims that my PK has a different data type length.  The PK is set up as following: (right('000000'+CONVERT(nvarchar,[CaseNumber],0),(6)))  ... should that not mean that it is the same as the other field is set to nvarchar(50)?

I know I could just delete all my relationships and use the casenumber field which is an int (identity) field but I would rather not recode all of that.

Answer (score 1):

No.

The data type of that expression is `nvarchar(6)` so you would need to cast the expression to `nvarchar(50)` to avoid the complaints about mismatching lengths.

```
   DECLARE @v SQL_VARIANT =RIGHT('000000'+CONVERT([NVARCHAR](50),123,0),(6))

   SELECT    CAST(SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@v, 'BaseType') AS VARCHAR(30)) AS BaseType,   
             CAST(SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@v, 'MaxLength') AS INT) AS MaxLength
```

Returns

```
BaseType                       MaxLength
------------------------------ -----------
nvarchar                       12
```

That is the size in bytes though so divide 12 by 2 to get the number of unicode characters.

Comment: @Martin well thats odd!  When I type (right('000000'+CONVERT([nvarchar](50),[CaseNumber],0),(6))) it deletes the (50) after nvarchar.  I already had it set in that manner.

Comment: But you run it through `RIGHT(,6)` after the `nvarchar(50)` cast and that returns `nvarchar(6)`

Comment: @Martin the actual code I used is as follows:  GO
USE newCityCollection
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PropertyInformation] ADD [CaseNumberKey] AS  RIGHT('000000' + CAST(CaseNumber AS NVARCHAR(50)), 6) PERSISTED NOT NULL
GO

Comment: Yep. My comment above still applies to that.

Comment: Okay I see. So by changing the 6 to 50 should solve the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: @korrowan - No because that won't give you a 6 digit string any more you need to wrap the whole thing in `cast(<your_expression> as nvarchar(50))`. You might also have to wrap it in an `isnull` as well to use it in a PK. Not sure on that. I'd probably bite the bullet and do the recoding sooner rather than later anyway. This is not a good way of storing numeric data!